# How to remove this error from "DIR" results : "File name is too long" from printing in console

Tags: linux, windows, cmd

My question is simple , for both windows and linux :

How to remove this error message from any search result 
"The directory/filename is too long"
By remove I mean , do not print in console.

Example :
dir /s/b *BlaBla.java

or
ls -R | grep *BlaBla.java

Answer (score 0):

Discard error text output (`stderr`) of command

[`cmd` Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```
dir /s /b *BlaBla.java 2> NUL
```

[`bash` Redirection:](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-redirection.html)

```
ls -R 2> /dev/null | grep *BlaBla.java
```